# Error resconf using OVSDB plugin

Tags: opendaylight

I'm using ODL-Carbon and trying to get a simple REST:

> http://ip-controller:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1/

but I get this error message:

```
> {
>     "errors": {
>         "error": [
>             {
>                 "error-type": "application",
>                 "error-tag": "operation-failed",
>                 "error-message": "Error executeRead ReadData for path /(urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:network-topology?revision=2013-10-21)network-topology/topology/topology[{(urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:network-topology?revision=2013-10-21)topology-id=ovsdb:1}]",
>                 "error-info": "org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.exceptions.NotInitializedException:
> Found primary shard member-1-shard-topology-config but it's not
> initialized yet. Please try again later\n\tat
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.shardmanager.ShardManager.createNotInitializedException(ShardManager.java:948)\n\tat
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.shardmanager.ShardManager.onShardNotInitializedTimeout(ShardManager.java:769)\n\tat
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.shardmanager.ShardManager.handleCommand(ShardManager.java:251)\n\tat
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.common.actor.AbstractUntypedPersistentActor.onReceiveCommand(AbstractUntypedPersistentActor.java:31)\n\tat
> akka.persistence.UntypedPersistentActor.onReceive(PersistentActor.scala:170)\n\tat
> org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.common.actor.MeteringBehavior.apply(MeteringBehavior.java:104)\n\tat
> akka.actor.ActorCell$$anonfun$become$1.applyOrElse(ActorCell.scala:544)\n\tat
> akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:502)\n\tat
> akka.persistence.UntypedPersistentActor.akka$persistence$Eventsourced$$super$aroundReceive(PersistentActor.scala:168)\n\tat
> akka.persistence.Eventsourced$$anon$1.stateReceive(Eventsourced.scala:727)\n\tat
> akka.persistence.Eventsourced$class.aroundReceive(Eventsourced.scala:183)\n\tat
> akka.persistence.UntypedPersistentActor.aroundReceive(PersistentActor.scala:168)\n\tat
> akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)\n\tat
> akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)\n\tat
> akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)\n\tat
> akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)\n\tat
> akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)\n\tat
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)\n\tat
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)\n\tat
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)\n\tat
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)\n"
>             }
>         ]
>     } }
```

My OS is Debian 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen this "it's not initialized yet. Please try again later" NotInitializedException, but it seems to indicate that the Data Store is not ready.. either you just need to wait a bit, or it perhaps there was serious error during start up.  Have you checked if your karaf.log has any errors that could explain why?